# Copying Files To a Dynamic Folder Using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a VBA code to create a folder every day I run it, based on the date. I use the MkDir for this;

```
MkDir "C:\Users\Stark\Desktop\Automation\Report" & " " & Format$(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Once this folder is created, I have to copy a few files to this folder on which I will have to work. Since this path keeps changing every time I run, I am not sure how to copy files to the newly created folder in such a case. The FileCopy function throws an error if I use the same path as mentioned above.

```
FileCopy "C:\Users\Stark\Desktop\Templates\RawData.xlsx", "C:\Users\Stark\Desktop\Automation\Report" & " " & Format$(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")\RawData.xlsx"
```

This part throws an error when I want to copy the file from Templates folder to the newly created folder.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Maybe you try to show us your sample which throws an error.

Comment: FileCopy "C:\Users\Stark\Desktop\Templates\RawData.xlsx", "C:\Users\Stark\Desktop\Automation\Report" & " " & Format$(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")\RawData.xlsx"

Comment: @start1208: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs well here, if I correct the concatenation at the end of the FileCopy-line:

`\RawData.xlsx"` must be concatenated properly using a `&` (like you do in the other places too):

```
FileCopy "C:\Users\Stark\Desktop\Templates\RawData.xlsx", "C:\Users\Stark\Desktop\Automation\Report" & " " & Format$(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & "\RawData.xlsx"
```

Comment: This helps. Thanks